# How can I load a single tag in a XML file into a paragraph tag in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, xml, load

I wanna load a single XML tag with the name 'QWERTY' into a 'p' tag in HTML with JavaScript, how can I do this?

Comment: It is very hard to know what you want without you give us an example and the expected result. Consider edit your question. See [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Load the XML from an AJAX request. [Parse](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_parser.asp) the XML. [Retrieve](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_dom.asp) the element from the XML Dom. Then add to the HTML element.

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest){// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}else{// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", XML_FILE, false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; //parse the XML

//retrieve the XML element you want
var v = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("QWERTY")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

//add the xml value to the html element
document.getElementById("paragraph-id").innerHTML = v;
```

Comment: And can someone explain why I received a negative one? It's a straightforward answer and it works and completely answers the question asked.

Comment: @John was this what you were looking for?